# C# .NET dynamic button display in listbox possible graphics glitch

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, listbox

I am adding some buttons in my listbox which comes dynamically and are created at runtime based on the number of rows I am feching from my database.

The code works fine, but when there are more rows a scroll bar appears, and when I scroll down there is a graphics type problem in viewing the buttons - they tend to move from their positions, but when I hover over them they go back to the positions they are supposed to be in.

How it looks before I scroll:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyy8B.jpg

After scrolling:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwnk4.jpg

Why is this happening...???

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DAL;
using BLL;

namespace PL
{
public partial class ApproveLeave : Form
{
    public int id;
    public int i = 0;
    public int count = 0;
    public String[] datestring = new String[100];
    public int[] eid = new int[100];
    public String[] type = new String[100];
    public int c = 0;


    public ApproveLeave()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Leaves leave = new Leaves();
        var btn=(Button)sender;
        String s = btn.Name.Substring(6);
        String sr;
        for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
        {
            if (a.ToString() == s)
            {
                leave._Date = Convert.ToDateTime(datestring[a]);
                leave.type = type[a];
                leave.EmpID = eid[a];
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }



        sr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to approve...?", "LMS", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo).ToString();
        if (sr == "Yes")
        {
            EmployeeHandler obj = new EmployeeHandler();
            obj.updatestatus(leave);

            ApproveLeave al = new ApproveLeave();
            al.id = id;
            Select frm = this.MdiParent as Select;
            al.MdiParent = frm;             
            al.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            al._show();
            al.Show();


        }
        else
        {

        }

    }

    public void _show()
    {
        EmployeeHandler obj = new EmployeeHandler();
        List<Leaves> al = new List<Leaves>();
        Leaves empid = new Leaves();
        String str;



        empid.EmpID = id;



        al = obj.ApproveLeave(empid);
        if (al != null )
        {
        str = "ID"+"   "+"Name"+"     "+"Date"+"               "+"Type";
        listBox1.Items.Add(str);
        str = "--------------------------------------------------------";
        listBox1.Items.Add(str);

            foreach (Leaves item in al)
            {

                str = item.EmpID.ToString() + "   " + item.empname + "   " + item._Date.ToString().Substring(0, item._Date.ToString().LastIndexOf(" ") - 8) + "   " + item.type;
                eid[c] = item.EmpID;
                datestring[c] = item._Date.ToString();
                type[c] = item.type;
                c++;


                if (listBox1.Items.Contains(str))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                    str = "   ";
                    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                    str = "   ";
                    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                }
                count++;
                int j = count;
                Button[] button = new Button[j];
                for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                {

                    button[i] = new Button();
                    button[i].Location = new Point(200, 20 + (i * 40));
                    button[i].Name = "button" + i;
                    button[i].Text = "Approve";
                    button[i].Click += new EventHandler(button_click);


                    listBox1.Controls.Add(button[i]);
                }

            }   
        }

    }

    private void ApproveLeave_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Posting your code is always better plus you should precise the kind of application you're developping (i.e. ASP.NET, WPF, WinForm, etc...)

Comment: Yes - please post your code :-)

Comment: Thanks for your replies '''  i am making a small winform application of leave management system using c# in .NET and as i am new to it i dont know much about it ... please ask if you need any other details :)

Comment: Not a real answer to why this is happening, but it feels weird that you'd doing this in a list box instead of just using a flow layout panel with labels and buttons. Another option would be to enable user painting the list box items and handle button clicks programmatically to trigger an action when the user clicks the drawn button.